# cscope : finding functions calling 'member functions'

Tags: c++, ctags, cscope

I'm working on a C++ project with huge codebase. I use cscope with ctags to browse the files. Consider the following piece of code :

```
Class A {
 public:
  int n;
  int foo();
}

Class B {
 public:
  int x;
  int foo();
}
```

Now i want to find all the functions, who are calling `class A`'s `foo()`.(i.e. through A's object, like `A a; a.foo();`). The problem is, when I do a search for functions calling `foo`, the functions calling `Class B`'s foo also gets listed. Since the code base is huge, I have to manually read line by line and check which is which. Is there any way to directly get a list of functions calling `class A'`s `foo()` ?

Comment: Make A's `foo()` private and recompile. You'll find in short order *almost* every non-friended place you're no longer legally accessing it. `B::foo()` will still be legit code. The entrails you won't find are instances of `A` within `A` member code, but this should significantly reduce the load. Or better still, just rename it in the class decl to `fooX()`. That would find them all. And any engineer that says they never use global-search-by-compilation-failure is lying to you.

Comment: i'm  using cmake to build the project. Building the code with the changes you mentioned would break the building process at the very first error.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayananSaravanan And what's the problem with that? Fix each error as you find it. Most important thing is to have a reliable method, especially when the code base is huge.

Comment: Ah, well that does indeed blow chunks. Unless you're in the mood to recompile N times for N usages, short of static analysis and a call-graph, you're somewhat sol.

Comment: Try my tool CodeQuery, which combines both cscope and ctags to provide more information, but it still doesn't do what you're requesting. An idea for a future feature. https://github.com/ruben2020/codequery

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tool for source code analysis?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761282/tool-for-source-code-analysis)